# Соответствие между меняющейся кнопкой и картинками

Tags: html, javascript, css

Есть веб-узел и три файла-изображения для меняющейся кнопки-ссылки. Как увидеть, что эти три файла "принадлежат" именно данной кнопке, а не другой? Чтобы можно было их изменить, например, рисунок кнопки при наведении курсора с овальной на прямоугольную.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотреть исходный код страницы (скорей всего это будет JavaScript).